Using declare_id with Environment Variables
I’m wondering if it's possible to use:
declare_id!(ENV::PROGRAM_ID);
This would allow me to work with several developers without needing to share:
wallet = "~/.config/solana/id.json"

This could maybe work as it is suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73728009/anchor-declare-id-with-environment-variable-environment-variables-in-macros

The macro was just updated in v2.1 with PR https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/pull/2348 to allow for data from different sources, so you can now actually do the following:
solana_program::declare_id!(&std::env!("TEST"));

But this will not work with keypairs until the same work is done for the Keypair type.
